# MySQL SELECT from 2 different Tables with WHERE clause on 2 Tables and 1 result NULL

Tags: mysql, join, select, left-join, outer-join

I am trying to get the **ordered qty** in the `cart_items` table and the **shipped qty** in the `shipping_table`.  Problem is, some `skus` haven't shipped yet and I can either A) only pull the items shipped or B) not have the correct total shipped qty.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
`shipping_table`    
id  |  invoice  | sku   | qty  | order_id
99  |   104     | 15628 |  1   |  9313
98  |   104     | 34929 |  2   |  9313
97  |   103     | 34929 |  1   |  9313
96  |   102     | 15628 |  87  |  9999
95  |   101     | 34929 |  32  |  9999
94  |   100     | 35870 |  6   |  9999


`cart_items`    
id     |  cart_id | sku   | qty
64903  |  4935153 | 15628 |  1  
65108  |  4935153 | 34929 |  4  
65109  |  4935153 | 35870 |  4
```

In this result we should see that sku 35870 hasn't shipped any items, 15628 has shipped, and sku 34929 only has shipped 3 items.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
sku   | total_qty | total_shipped_qty
15628 |      1    |          1
34929 |      4    |          3
35870 |      4    |          NULL
```

**WRONG RESULT A**

This one is close but since I am querying on an `order_id` which is only in one table it doesn't pull the `total_qty` for the sku 35870 because it is not in `shipping_table` yet (it hasn't shipped at all).

```
SELECT 
    CT.sku, 
    MT.`qty` as total_qty, 
    SUM(CT.`qty`) as total_shipped_qty 
FROM `shipping_table` CT 
        LEFT JOIN 
     `cart_items` MT ON MT.sku = CT.sku 
WHERE MT.`cart_id` = '4935153' AND CT.`order_id` = '9313'
GROUP BY MT.sku

sku   | total_qty | total_shipped_qty
15628 |      1    |          1
34929 |      4    |          3
```

**WRONG RESULT B**

Here is something close but it is the incorrect `total_shipped_qty` values because it is looking at the Total in the whole `shipping_table`. This result looks like it sums up the WHOLE qtys for the `shipping_table`.

```
SELECT 
    CT.sku, 
    MT.`qty` as total_qty, 
    SUM(CT.`qty`) as total_shipped_qty 
FROM `shipping_table` CT 
        LEFT JOIN 
     `cart_items` MT ON MT.sku = CT.sku 
WHERE MT.`cart_id` = '4935153'
GROUP BY MT.sku

sku   | total_qty | total_shipped_qty
15628 |      1    |          88
34929 |      4    |          35
35870 |      4    |          6
```

Comment: From clause should be Cart_items table and left join for shipping_table  `SELECT 
    CT.sku, 
    MT.qty as total_qty, 
    SUM(CT.qty) as total_shipped_qty 
FROM cart_items MT  
        LEFT JOIN 
      shipping_table CT ON MT.sku = CT.sku 
WHERE MT.cart_id = '4935153'
GROUP BY MT.sku`

Comment: I have tried this before as well:  Same thing as WRONG RESULT B

Comment: post your sample table data too

Comment: @JYoThI Posted Sample data

Answer (score 0):

Use Scalar Subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=951fd832d555f84041607ada93477e97)**

```
SELECT 
     CT.sku, 
     qty as total_qty, 
    (select SUM(qty) from shipping_table MT where CT.sku=MT.sku group by MT.sku) 
    as total_shipped_qty 
FROM cart_items CT
      WHERE CT.cart_id = '4935153'
```

Comment: Same result as Wrong Result A

Comment: can u please add your sample data in your question like your expected output - it will help @ToddN

Comment: Posted sample data

Comment: @ToddN, Updated my answer - you can check now

Comment: I get Wrong Result B.  I have added another `order_id` into my sample data for `shipping_table` so you can see why I get this data.